# Binning pandas data by top N percent

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas series (as part of a larger data frame) like the below:

```
0        7416
1       10630
2        7086
3        2091
4        3995
5        1304
6         519
7        1262
8        3676
9        2371
10       5346
11        912
12       3653
13       1093
14       2986
15       2951
16      11859
```

I would like to group rows based on the following quantiles:

```
Top 0-5%
Top 6-10%
Top 11-25%
Top 26-50%
Top 51-75%
Top 76-100%
```

First I started by using `pd.rank()` on the data and then I planned on then using `pd.cut()` to cut the data into bins, but it does not seem like this accepts top N%, rather it accepts explicit bin edges.  Is there an easy way to do this in pandas, or do I need to create a lambda/apply function which calculates which bin each of the ranked items should be placed in.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind?

```
pd.qcut(data, [0.05, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1])
```

Comment: Not quite.  When I apply this to my data set it says there are 419 posts in the top 0-5% percentile, when in actuality in my data set of 1674 samples, there should only be 84 samples within the top 5%

Comment: What if you reverse the order in the array?

Comment: [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 0.9, 0.95, 1] is what I mean

Answer (score 0):

Slightly modified version:

> pd.qcut(data, [0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1])

Otherwise it gives me NaN if dataset below 0.05 (5%).